# How the name of this construct and where can I read about it?

Tags: java

Some exapmle

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(...) {
   @Override
   protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
   .....
 }
}
```

I don't know how it works.
I am bit confused in this plase

JsonArrayRequest(...) {**here**}

First we call constructor then somehow override the method.

ps: sorry for the stupid question, I'm a Python Developer :)

Comment: Finding a suitable duplicate took a while, but here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an anonymous class. Anonymous classes are implementations of `Interfaces` or abstract classes that could otherwise not be instantiated.
You can take a closer look at the documentation by Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html